# Swift equivalent of MessageDigest in Java?

Tags: java, ios, swift, encryption, cryptoswift

I am trying to do auth encryption in my app, its working for kotlin but not for swift. We are trying to use "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding". Below kotlin code to get secret key. but my swift code is returning different result then kotlin.

```
private fun getSecretKey(): SecretKey {
        val messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
        val key = messageDigest.digest(SECRET_KEY.toByteArray(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
            .copyOfRange(0, 16)
        return SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")

    }
```

How can I achieve this in Swift? What is the equivalent of MessageDigest.getInstance in swift.

Comment: “my swift code is returning different result” – I can see no Swift code in your question.

Comment: Note that this Kotlin code shows terrible cryptgraphic practices. Taking a normal cryptographic hash over a password does not make a secure key. You'd need a Password Based Key Derivation Function or PBKDF for that. Java has PBKDF2 in the default JRE by Oracle. So you should replace the code above altogether instead of copying it.

Comment: @MartinR He did that in his previous question, he just reposted the partial question when he didn't get a quick answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not equivalent of *SecretKeySpec*. But this Java class mainly wraps a binary key. The below code just returns the binary key data.

For Swift 4:

```
    let secretKey = "secret"
    let data = Data(secretKey.utf8)
    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    data.withUnsafeBytes { 
        _ = CC_SHA1($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
    }
    return data
```